# How is the Antim Sanskar of unmarried hindu Women done?

Tags: rituals, women, death

What is the procedure of Antim Sanskar when a unmarried women dies? Does she dress like a bride? Who gives the agni to her pyre?

Comment: Are u asking for married women or unmarried women? I answered the Q for the title it had .. now user Aby changed it totally

Comment: @Rickross in title unmarried and in body married. Mismatch... unclear

Comment: @RaunakThakar clear your question on what you want. Married or unmarried.  Title unmarried and body married. I have rolled back it to your original to clear this doubt because if you want unmarried then body has to be changed!

Comment: Yes I checked the title of the original and answered @AkshayS

Comment: @Rickross I have rolled back to original. What if OP wants unmarried? So the change in title to married becomes mistake in that case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of your question is asking for unmarried girls. And my answer is for that query.

If you are asking about married ladies then your question is an exact duplicate of :[Who should do Antim Sanskar (funeral rites) of married woman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/who-should-do-antim-sanskar-funeral-rites-of-married-woman)

**For Unmarried girls:**

According to Baudhayana such women should NOT be cremated. But at the same time it also says that some people do perform last rites for such women.

See the following verses:

> Among people belonging to the same ancestry, the relationship based on
>   common ancestry extends to the seventh generation. 3
>
> Only a bath is prescribed when a child dies before it is seven months
>   old or before teething. 4 When a child dies before it is 3 years old
>   or before teething, no offerings of food or water are prescribed, and
>   it should not be cremated.
>
> 5 **The same is true when unmarried girls die.**
>
> 6 **Some do perform these rites for married women,** 7but they do it
>   just to curry favour with people; ritual formulas are thought not to
>   apply to women.
>
> **Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 1.11.11.1-7**

And, should not be cremated means they have to be buried.

**For married women:**

> Having cremated a becoming wife, dead before, with the fire of the
>   vessel, one should get himself re-married without delay [and
>   consecrate the Fire again]. (5)
>
> A twice-born person, who is conversant with religious laws, should
>   cremate a good-charactered wife of the same caste, who dies before,
>   with the sacrificial vessel according to the Agnihotra- method. (6)
>
> One who, having his first wife living, cremates the second wife with
>   the Vaitanika is equal to the destroyer of a Brahmana. (7)
>
> **Katyayana Smriti Chapter 20**

So, for married ladies their husbands should do the final rites. In husband's absence it is the sons who should do it.